# text on click function is not working in d3 V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make axis ticks clickable in parallel coordinates in d3 v4.
I have followed the basic steps but still the ticks are not getting clickable.

Here is the code snippet.

```
svg.selectAll(".axis").selectAll(".tick text").on('click', function() {    
    console.log("on clicked");    
});
```

Here is the plunkr link for the full code.(basically concerning line no between 293 -301)
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5SFbKot7sxD1qMqJKvj?p=preview

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Nutrient Parallel Coordinates IV</title>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
var renderQueue = (function(func) {
  var _queue = [],                  // data to be rendered
      _rate = 1000,                 // number of calls per frame
      _invalidate = function() {},  // invalidate last render queue
      _clear = function() {};       // clearing function

  var rq = function(data) {
    if (data) rq.data(data);
    _invalidate();
    _clear();
    rq.render();
  };

  rq.render = function() {
    var valid = true;
    _invalidate = rq.invalidate = function() {
      valid = false;
    };

    function doFrame() {
      if (!valid) return true;
      var chunk = _queue.splice(0,_rate);
      chunk.map(func);
      timer_frame(doFrame);
    }

    doFrame();
  };

  rq.data = function(data) {
    _invalidate();
    _queue = data.slice(0);   // creates a copy of the data
    return rq;
  };

  rq.add = function(data) {
    _queue = _queue.concat(data);
  };

  rq.rate = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return _rate;
    _rate = value;
    return rq;
  };

  rq.remaining = function() {
    return _queue.length;
  };

  // clear the canvas
  rq.clear = function(func) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      _clear();
      return rq;
    }
    _clear = func;
    return rq;
  };

  rq.invalidate = _invalidate;

  var timer_frame = window.requestAnimationFrame
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
    || function(callback) { setTimeout(callback, 17); };

  return rq;
});

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
<script>

var temp = [];

var actives_test = [];


var margin = {top: 66, right: 110, bottom: 20, left: 188},
    width = document.body.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 340 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    innerHeight = height - 2;

var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["Radial Velocity", "Imaging", "Eclipse Timing Variations", "Astrometry", "Microlensing", "Orbital Brightness Modulation", "Pulsar Timing", "Pulsation Timing Variations", "Transit", "Transit Timing Variations"])
  .range(["#DB7F85", "#50AB84", "#4C6C86", "#C47DCB", "#B59248", "#DD6CA7", "#E15E5A", "#5DA5B3", "#725D82", "#54AF52", "#954D56", "#8C92E8", "#D8597D", "#AB9C27", "#D67D4B", "#D58323", "#BA89AD", "#357468", "#8F86C2", "#7D9E33", "#517C3F", "#9D5130", "#5E9ACF", "#776327", "#944F7E"]);

var types = {
  "Number": {
    key: "Number",
    coerce: function(d) { return +d; },
    extent: d3.extent,
    within: function(d, extent, dim) { return extent[0] <= dim.scale(d) && dim.scale(d) <= extent[1]; },
    defaultScale: d3.scaleLinear().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },
  "String": {
    key: "String",
    coerce: String,
    extent: function (data) { return data.sort(); },
    within: function(d, extent, dim) { return extent[0] <= dim.scale(d) && dim.scale(d) <= extent[1]; },
    defaultScale: d3.scalePoint().range([0, innerHeight])
  },
  "Date": {
    key: "Date",
    coerce: function(d) { return new Date(d); },
    extent: d3.extent,
    within: function(d, extent, dim) { return extent[0] <= dim.scale(d) && dim.scale(d) <= extent[1]; },
    defaultScale: d3.scaleTime().range([innerHeight, 0])
  }
};




var dimensions = [

  {
    key: "column1",
    type: types["Number"],
    scale: d3.scaleSqrt().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },
 {
    key: "column2",
   // description: "Food ",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },
  {
    key: "column3",
    type: types["Number"],
    scale: d3.scaleSqrt().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },
  {
    key: "column4",
   // description: "Food Group",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },
   {
    key: "column5",
    type: types["Number"],
    scale: d3.scaleSqrt().range([innerHeight, 0])
  },

   {
    key: "column6",
    //description: "Food Group",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },


   {
    key: "column7",
    //description: "Food Group",
    type: types["String"],
    axis: d3.axisLeft()
      .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        return d;
      })
  },

  ];


var xscale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(d3.range(dimensions.length))
    .range([0, width]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft();

var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "parcoords")
    .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
    .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var canvas = container.append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width * devicePixelRatio)
    .attr("height", height * devicePixelRatio)
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px")
    .style("margin-top", margin.top + "px")
    .style("margin-left", margin.left + "px");

var ctx = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'darken';
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.15;
ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
ctx.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);

//var output = d3.select("body").append("pre");

var axes = svg.selectAll(".axis")
    .data(dimensions)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class","axis")
    //.attr("class", function(d) { return "axis " + d.key.replace(/ /g, "_"); })
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + xscale(i) + ")"; });



d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    dimensions.forEach(function(p) {
      d[p.key] = !d[p.key] ? null : p.type.coerce(d[p.key]);
    });

    // truncate long text strings to fit in data table
    for (var key in d) {
      if (d[key] && d[key].length > 35) d[key] = d[key].slice(0,36);
    }
  });

  // type/dimension default setting happens here
  dimensions.forEach(function(dim) {
    if (!("domain" in dim)) {
      // detect domain using dimension type's extent function
      dim.domain = d3_functor(dim.type.extent)(data.map(function(d) { return d[dim.key]; }));
    }
    if (!("scale" in dim)) {
      // use type's default scale for dimension
      dim.scale = dim.type.defaultScale.copy();
    }
    dim.scale.domain(dim.domain);
  });

  var render = renderQueue(draw).rate(30);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.globalAlpha = d3.min([1.15/Math.pow(data.length,0.3),1]);
  render(data);

  axes.append("g")
      .each(function(d) {
        var renderAxis = "axis" in d
          ? d.axis.scale(d.scale)  // custom axis
          : yAxis.scale(d.scale);  // default axis
        d3.select(this).call(renderAxis);
      })
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return "description" in d ? d.description : d.key; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  axes.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(d.brush = d3.brushY()
          .extent([[-10,0], [10,height]])
          .on("start", brushstart)
          .on("brush", brush)
          .on("end", brushend)
        )
      })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);

  d3.selectAll(".axis.pl_discmethod .tick text")
    .style("fill", color);

var that = svg.selectAll(".axis").selectAll(".tick text");
console.log("that axis", that);


svg.selectAll(".axis").selectAll(".tick text").on('click', function() {

  console.log("on clicked");

});

  //output.text(d3.tsvFormat(data.slice(0,24)));

  function project(d) {
    return dimensions.map(function(p,i) {
      // check if data element has property and contains a value
      if (
        !(p.key in d) ||
        d[p.key] === null
      ) return null;

      return [xscale(i),p.scale(d[p.key])];
    });
  };

  function draw(d) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = color(d.pl_discmethod);
    ctx.beginPath();
    var coords = project(d);
    coords.forEach(function(p,i) {
      // this tricky bit avoids rendering null values as 0
      if (p === null) {
        // this bit renders horizontal lines on the previous/next
        // dimensions, so that sandwiched null values are visible
        if (i > 0) {
          var prev = coords[i-1];
          if (prev !== null) {
            ctx.moveTo(prev[0],prev[1]);
            ctx.lineTo(prev[0]+6,prev[1]);
          }
        }
        if (i < coords.length-1) {
          var next = coords[i+1];
          if (next !== null) {
            ctx.moveTo(next[0]-6,next[1]);
          }
        }
        return;
      }

      if (i == 0) {
        ctx.moveTo(p[0],p[1]);
        return;
      }

      ctx.lineTo(p[0],p[1]);
    });
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function brushstart() {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  }

  // Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
  function brush() {
    render.invalidate();

    //console.log("brushing");

   var actives = [];
    svg.selectAll(".axis .brush")
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d3.brushSelection(this);
      })
      .each(function(d) {
     // console.log("d", d);
        temp.push(d);
        actives.push({
          dimension: d,
          extent: d3.brushSelection(this)
        });
      });



    //  console.log("actives", actives);

    var selected = data.filter(function(d) {
      if (actives.every(function(active) {
          var dim = active.dimension;
         // console.log("dim", dim);
          // test if point is within extents for each active brush
          return dim.type.within(d[dim.key], active.extent, dim);
        })) {
        return true;
      }
    });

    // show ticks for active brush dimensions
    // and filter ticks to only those within brush extents
    /*
    svg.selectAll(".axis")
        .filter(function(d) {
          return actives.indexOf(d) > -1 ? true : false;
        })
        .classed("active", true)
        .each(function(dimension, i) {
          var extent = extents[i];
          d3.select(this)
            .selectAll(".tick text")
            .style("display", function(d) {
              var value = dimension.type.coerce(d);
              return dimension.type.within(value, extent, dimension) ? null : "none";
            });
        });

    // reset dimensions without active brushes
    svg.selectAll(".axis")
        .filter(function(d) {
          return actives.indexOf(d) > -1 ? false : true;
        })
        .classed("active", false)
        .selectAll(".tick text")
          .style("display", null);
    */
//  console.log("data", data);
//console.log("selected", selected);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.globalAlpha = d3.min([0.85/Math.pow(selected.length,0.3),1]);
    render(selected);

    //output.text(d3.tsvFormat(selected.slice(0,24)));
  }
});

function brushend () {
  console.log('brushend');

}

function d3_functor(v) {
  return typeof v === "function" ? v : function() { return v; };
};
</script>
```

Comment: The selection isn't working. I separated out the class and the text: http://plnkr.co/edit/GHj6WUZkeBVLQbowxIvs?p=preview

Comment: You have a `pointer-events:none` applied to `.axis .tick text` on line 36 in style.css. Take that out and the click event will work.